# Change QSpinBox Arrow Size Without Changing App Style

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to find a way to alter properties of a widget, such as size of a component or various borders and colours, without changing the default style of the widget (in this case, fusion). Still trying to get my head around style sheets in PyQT, could someone explain how to achieve the bigger arrow buttons without altering the style?

Thanks in advance.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyle("fusion")
    #Trying to change the arrow size here, while maintaining their "fusion" style
    app.setStyleSheet("QSpinBox::up-button { width: 32px; }"
                      "QSpinBox::down-button { width: 32px; }")
    windowExample = basicWindow()
    windowExample.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Without app.setStyleSheet][image: With app.setStyleSheet]

---

I'm using a Proxy Style for my sliders too in order to alter the slider size, hoping theres something similar for a spinbox:

```
class SliderProxyStyle(QProxyStyle):
    def pixelMetric(self, metric, option, widget):
        if metric == QStyle.PM_SliderThickness:
            return 20
        elif metric == QStyle.PM_SliderLength:
            return 40
        return super().pixelMetric(metric, option, widget)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, not with simple stylesheets, as explained at the bottom of the [sub-controls documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#sub-controls):

> With complex widgets such as QComboBox and QScrollBar, if one property or sub-control is customized, all the other properties or sub-controls must be customized as well."

Complex widgets also include all subclasses of QAbstractSpinBox, from which QSpinBox inherits, so if you alter any of the properties (except for background and foreground color), you have to provide everything else, as the basic implementation of the style will be ignored by using the basic QCommonStyle as fallback.

The only viable solution is to use a QProxyStyle and implement subControlRect for SC_SpinBoxUp, SC_SpinBoxDown and `SC_SpinBoxEditField`:

```
class Proxy(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def subControlRect(self, control, opt, subControl, widget=None):
        rect = super().subControlRect(control, opt, subControl, widget)
        if control == self.CC_SpinBox:
            if subControl in (self.SC_SpinBoxUp, self.SC_SpinBoxDown):
                rect.setLeft(opt.rect.width() - 32)
            elif subControl == self.SC_SpinBoxEditField:
                rect.setRight(opt.rect.width() - 32)
        return rect

# ...
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle(Proxy())
# ...
```

Comment: Tried this without any luck, except it's now also changed my sliders to a different format, perhaps because they are already altered with a proxy style class?

Comment: @Jkind9 note that you should *not* use the stylesheet on those spinboxes any more: as said, if you use stylesheets you're overriding the style (which would make the proxy implementation almost useless). The issue about sliders comes from the fact that depending on the style some attributes are used for slightly related widgets, you could ensure that `widget` is a QSpinBox instance (or even set your own property and check for it, if you want to style different spinboxes in different ways).

Comment: (actually, it's a bit strange that you get sliders changed as well, as they should not with fusion style; ensure that you're not already using another proxy style, or that you're not using a custom stylesheet like the QDarkStyleSheet.)

Comment: Yep I tried deleting the ```app.setStyle(___) ``` line too. I'm not using any style sheet other than fusion, and Im using a palette to alter the colours. It didn't seem to change the size of the buttons. I see, could you edit your answer to show how I'd correct the slider problem? As I said very new to PyQt I'm afraid!

Comment: If you delete that line, the proxy style will *not* be used. Check if you're using a stylesheet in any of the parents (or the QApplication as well).

Comment: Updated my question to show my Slider Proxy style, could this be the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229094/discussion-between-jkind9-and-musicamante).

Comment: Wait, you're *already* using another proxy style? You should have mentioned that. First of all, QStyle (and its subclasses, including QProxyStyle) and stylesheet don't work well together. Then, if you already have a proxy, implement the subControlRect in that.